# Angular Async Service - possible to subclass to re-use code?

Tags: angular

I have this Angular 9 async validation service. It serves two separate components... a time picker component and a date picker component.

I was thinking about breaking this service into 2 seperate services `TimeValidator` and `DateValidator` but still be able to reuse the code `searchTimeDate` and `validateTimeDate`.

To do this, is it possible to subclass `searchTimeDate` and `validateTimeDate` and extend it? I wasn't sure how I could do this and invoke `searchTimeDate` and `validateTimeDate`

```
export class TimeDateValidator {
  private getTimestamp(formData) {
    const minValue = moment('09:59', 'hh:mm');
    const maxValue = moment('18:01', 'hh:mm');
    const { hour, minute } = formData;

    const timeStamp = moment(`${hour}:${minute}`, 'hh:mm');

    if (timeStamp.isValid()) {
      return timeStamp.isBetween(minValue, maxValue);
    };
  }

  private getDatestamp(formData) {
    const dateFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
    const minValue = moment('01/01/2020', dateFormat);
    const maxValue = moment('12/31/2020', dateFormat);

    const dateStamp = moment(formData, dateFormat);;

    if (dateStamp.isValid()) {
      return dateStamp.isBetween(minValue, maxValue);
    }
  };

  private searchTimeDate(formData) {
    if (!formData) { return; }

    const isInBetween = this.getTimestamp(formData) || this.getDatestamp(formData);

    if (isInBetween) {
      return null;
    }

    return { notInBetween: true };
  }


  validateTimeDate(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> => (
     of(control.value).pipe(map((val) => this.searchTimeDate(val)))
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create two other services you need extending from TimeDataValidator and just overload the methods you want to change.

```
export class subclass1 extends TimeDateValidator {
  private searchTimeDate(formData) {
    // custom code.
  }

  validateTimeDate(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    // custom code.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a service file for this two functions also and implement your logic there. Create a contructor in the Time validator class and inject both the service in it if required

Seperate the service as Time Validator and Date Validator
And inject a service into a single file like inject the date validator from time validator or vice versa but don't do on both end as it will create a circular dependency

Answer (score 1):

Just extract the method you want to it's own class and import the class where you need to access the method.
Instantiate the class and call the method. (You could use constructor Injection here)